# socket programming code not running forever

Tags: java

I have a 2 nodes that should always communicate with each other, but they don't seem to talk for more than 1 interaction. After successfully sending and receiving 1 message, they stop.
My code looks like this:
The initiator:

```
try {
   Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
   OutputStream toNode = client.getOutputStream();
   DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(toNode);
   out.writeUTF("Start:Message");
   System.out.println("Sent data");
   InputStream fromNode = client.getInputStream();
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fromNode);
   if(in.readUTF().equals("Return Message")) {
      System.out.println("Received data");
      out.writeUTF("Main:Message");
      System.out.println("Sent data again");
   }

   else
      System.out.println("Error");
   client.close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The responder:

```
while(true) {
   Socket server;
   try {
      server = s.accept();
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
      String msg = in.readUTF();
      String[] broken_msg = msg.split(":");
      if(broken_msg.length > 0)
         System.out.println("Looping");
      String ret;
      if (broken[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
         ret = "Return Message";
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
         out.writeUTF(ret);
      }

      else if (broken[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Main")) {
         //Do Useful work     
      }
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

My output looks like this:

> Looping

and:

> Sent data
>   Received data
>   Sent data again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping around the `accept()` call, accepting new connections, but your actual I/O code only reads one message per connection. You need an inner loop around the `readUTF()` calls, handling the entire connection until `EOFException` is thrown. Normally all the I/O for a connection is handled in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

In order for programs to do repetitive actions, you would generally use looping of some sort, including for loops, while loops and do-while loops. For something like this where you don't know how many times you'd need to communicate in advance, then you would need to use a while loop, not a for loop.

Having said that, you have no while loops whatsoever inside of your connection code... so without code that would allow continued communication, your program will stop, exactly as you've programmed it to do.

Solution: fix this. Put in while loops where continued communication is needed.

Comment: I want the first code block to pass a message only twice, so I added two `out.writeUTF()` functions. Whereas the node that listens has a `while(true)` which should make it run forever. But it seemed to have got only 1 of the 2 messages I sent.

Comment: That `while (true)` is only for accepting connections. It has nothing to do with communication once a connection is established. Please walk through your code mentally, try to understand what it's doing.